# OpenCL compilation approach performance difference OSX

Tags: macos, opencl, llvm

I'm wondering what the exact difference between compiling OpenCL programs on OSX with clBuildProgram compiled from source versus using the Xcode built in or commandline `openclc` LLVM compiler.

1) does the driver invoke the same llvm compiler?

2) default for openclc is -O1 according to Apple docs is this the case for clBuildProgram as well?

3) are there any other differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `clCreateProgramWithSource` uses an equivalent of passing -Os optimization level to `openclc` and loading the binary kernel with `clCreateProgramWithBinary`.

It doesn't seem to be documented how to pass -O3 on the API level.
Performance hit is about 40% for a complex kernel with lots of mixed float and int calculations.